# How to write a code to generate a new jframe of full screen by click a button on another jframe?

Tags: java

How to write a code to generate a new jframe of full screen by click a button on another jframe ? 
like, if i create a button on jFrame1 & want to open another say jFrame2 in fullscreen, how will i do that ?  what will be the necessary mousePressed event code i have to write ?

I have tried using below code :

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());  
this.setSize(xSize,ySize);
```

But it gives a exception

Comment: Post a minimal, complete, verifiable example.  Post the full exception stack trace.  Are you having trouble registering the click?  Or creating the jFrame?  What is `this`?

Comment: Do you mean full screen exclusive mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `JFrame#setExtendedState` and pass it `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`, make sure you are calling it on the right instance of `JFrame` thought

Buttons are managed via `ActionListener`s, not `MouseListener`s.

See [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write ActionListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Beware, generally it's not a good idea to use multiple frames as it can be confusing to users, generally it's better to use things like `JTabbedPane` or `CardLayout`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
device.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600, 32, 60));

Answer (score 1):

Here is some base code for you to use. You might need to play around with it though.

```
        jButton = new javax.swing.JButton(); // inside your init(); method        

        jButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() { // also inside your init(); method
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // open other JFrame here
            // JFrame2.setVisible(true); or something along those lines
        }
```

Basically, you create a JButton, then add an action performed event to the button that will open the new JFrame2.

I hope I helped. Please do comment if something is unclear.

Best of Luck!